# prevent the click on <ion-side-menu-content> to close the <ion-side-menu>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have  -

```
<ion-side-menu>
    ....
</ion-side-menu>
<ion-side-menu-content>
    ....
</ion-side-menu-content>
```

[**Here Demo**](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/QwamEW)

As you can see , any clicking on the `<ion-side-menu-content>` area will close its sibling - `<ion-side-menu>` ,

how could I prevent it ?

mean - if the `<ion-side-menu>` is open , and I clicked on the `<ion-side-menu-content>` area , the `<ion-side-menu>` **still will be open** .

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$event.stoppropagation()`

Comment: The event you are trying to stop from happening.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.